# Edge Side Includes in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, symfony, esi

I've been looking at the use of ESI tags in Symfony through Varnish and I'm wondering if the same thing can be done in Laravel, and if so, how?

A Senior Developer at work wants us to switch from Laravel to Symfony and is currently using ESI tags as a reason to make the switch, leading me to believe it's exclusive to Symfony, but that doesn't make sense from what I've read of it.

Comment: It can be done in raw php, so there must be a way to do it in Laravel. But honestly, Symfony is just a better framework, I highly support his decision regardless.

Answer (score 1):

I know it's an old question but as it comes first when looking for Laravel ESI on Google, it should be known that you can handle ESI in Laravel with [Laravel HttpCache](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-httpcache#esi) by Barry vd. Heuvel.

Answer (score -3):

Laravel uses Blade for templating.

You can include a file like `@include('shared.errors')`

Please refer to Laravel's documentation on usage of Blade [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/blade)

Comment: Not the same thing, you can't include a remote view through Blade.